# concatenate inputs in verilog

Tags: verilog

In my module I am taking two input 8-bits.

```
mymodule(input clk, input [7:0] AS_1,input [7:0] AS_2, output [7:0] AS)
```

Now I want to create a container that will keep both inputs, I mean I want to join them in a single one. I want to do something like that:

```
reg [15:0] JOIN = AS_1 and AS_2 ---> all their bits should be arranged in a single container
```

But I don't know whether it should be a reg type or wire or something else, because I'll need to make other operations with that JOIN

Any help, advise or suggestion would be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
wire [15:0] joined;
assign joined = {AS_1, AS_2};
```

That creates a wire which always has the joined value.

The braces can be used in most places to concatenate values like this.

Comment: ok but the point is that if I had to do something like this  joined = joined & 8'b11110000; statement would it work?

Comment: @BlediBoss I think that might be a combinatorial loop depending on how you write it, why not have `joined_masked = joined & mask`.

Comment: @BlediBoss - pre_randomize above is correct, generally in Verilog it's best to adopt a style where every variable is assigned to in only one place. Whether you want reg or wire, and assign versus "<=" in an always block, is determined by what else you want to do and whether you want it immediate or on a clock edge.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do additional calculations to `JOIN` I would recommend the following:

```
reg [15:0] JOIN;
always @* begin
  JOIN = {AS_1,AS_2};
  JOIN[8:0] = JOIN[8:0] & mask;
  // ... other code
end
```

If your simulator supports SystemVerilog, I will recommend you use `logic` instead of `reg`. Technically the two are the same, however for readability it is best to use `reg` for intended flops and `logic` for intended combination values.

Comment: AS I can see you are defining JOIN as a single bit, and assigning later as if it was 8 bit.! But it is supposed to be 16 bits.

Comment: @BlediBoss, good catch. It was a typo. I updated it to a 16 bit bus.